# FLEX 4.5: Displaying Horizontal/Vertical scrollbar on Canvas

Tags: apache-flex, canvas, flex4, scrollbar

I have a canvas lets say the size of it on the screen is 500x500. But I want the actual canvas size to be 1000x500 making the other half scrollable. How can I make a blank canvas with that specification?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<s:Group width="500" height="500">
    <s:Scroller left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0">
        <s:Group width="1000" height="500" />
    </s:Scroller>
</s:Group>
```

Comment: thanks for this... im a newbie, where should i put the mx:Canvas tag?

Comment: `mx:Canvas` is obsolete in Flex 4. Use `s:Group`.

Comment: hmmm.... I am using objecthandler package (used tomove rotate resize objects on the fly) and sadly it uses canvas

Comment: Ok. Just replace inner group with canvas.

Comment: it could be replaced by `navigatorContent`